# JQuery ajaxSetup - appending global data to FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

I am passing a global parameter in all jquery ajax requests using the `ajaxSetup` function like below

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        csrf: csrfValue
    }
});
```

This works fine for all requests except when I do a ajax file upload

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('attachedFile', file);
$.ajax({
         url: '/fileUpload',
         data: formData,
         success: function() {
           ....
         }
});
```

Since I am using a `FormData`, the `csrf` param is not getting appended. Is there a proper way to append common data to all types of ajax requests?

Comment: Try with append `csrf: csrfValue` with data. Like this, `data:formData+csrf+"="+csrfValue`.

Comment: Can you show other request snippet where ajaxsetup working fine?

Comment: @Manwal it works for all requests where the data is just a json object.

Comment: So i think you need to manually append data into formdata.

Comment: Yes, `formData.append('csrf', csrfValue)` works but I looking for a way to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by using [$.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) and [$.ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/) to merge the default data with the data you've provided:
`UPDATED:`

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (originalOptions.data instanceof FormData) { 
         originalOptions.data.append(csrfParamName, csrfParamValue); 
    }
});
```

Comment: This unfortunately is not working. Additional parameters to formData is working only when you use its append method :(.

Comment: Don't think `$.extend` will ever work `FormData` but using `ajaxPrefilter` seems like a good option. I was able to do something like 

`if (originalOptions.data instanceof FormData) {
            originalOptions.data.append(csrfParamName, csrfParamValue);
        }`

Comment: @Krishnaraj $.extend behaves like your append. It merges the two objects. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: I believe the behaviour is different. Refer this screenshot - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-yIKxPwXBJ2TndKWFVDN1pQMUE/view?usp=sharing. `data1` is 'extended' while `data2` is 'appended'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does not work because you are using FormData. 
Add the `csrfValue` to your ajax data  or
add a hidden field inside your form

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ csrfValue }}"?>
```